# How does encoding algorithm handle separate bit blocks

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression, hamming-code

I am learning about how Hamming code works. In low level encoding/decoding what are the protocols to separate code blocks? Let's say you have a (15, 11) Hamming code block, do you add extra bits in-between to separate them? Also what if on the last block you have extra spaces?

```
linear codes in matrix representation:
bit block                   next bit block                last block
1 1 1 1                       0 0 0 1                      1 0 0 1
0 0 1 1   +     ???     +     0 0 0 1      +    ...   +    1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1                       0 0 0 1                      ? ? ? ?
0 1 0 1                       0 0 0 1                      ? ? ? ?
```

Comment: @user3386109 thank you!! I made a mistake. Huffman code shouldn't be in this question since all leaves will be an independent codeword. What happens when the last block of Hamming contains less data bits than the rest? As if `(the source data bits length) %  11 != 0` in this case? Or do people pick a dynamically sized block length to partition the original data bits?